# CakePHP FormHelper Input Date

Tags: date, cakephp, formhelper

I have following question. When I use this Helper:

```
echo $this->Form->input('start_date', array('required'=>false, 'class'=>'form-control date'));
```

I get following output:

[image]

Where can I change this output type? I tried it in

```
/lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php
```

I found in this lib file, that the Helper gets the function `__getInput()` and in the `date` case, following sub function:

```
case 'date':
   $options['value'] = $selected;
   return $this->dateTime($fieldName, $dateFormat, null, $options);
```

But in the function `dateTime()` I got lost. Is there any updated Helper out or is there a simple trick to change the HTML-output format?

Thanks & regards

Comment: To what exactly do you want to change it?

Comment: In one input field with a class to run a jquery datepicker...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set input type as text

```
echo $this->Form->input('start_date', array('type'=>'text','required'=>false, 'class'=>'form-control date'));
```